# How to get rid of "extern" keyword with public variables declaration in Rhapsody?

Tags: c, rhapsody

In IBM Rational Rhapsody, when you declare a variable as public, the code generator makes it `extern` (in .h file). How can I remove this `extern` qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

For the specification, the declaration is controlled by this property:
CPP_CG::WriterTemplates::GlobalAttributeSpec

There is also a property:
CPP_CG::WriterTemplates::GlobalAttributeImp (for the implementation)

Keep in mind that changes can result in compilation problems if the two properties are not changed in tandem.

If you are changing these properties at a level above an individual variable, this can also have implications for auto-generated code.

Changes to the default values can also have implications for roundtripping the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for delay. I can see the `$extern`internal var., but is there any other way, except the template edit? where I can find this internal variable setup?

Answer (score 0):

If your attribute does not belong to a class and instead of it is defined under a namespace then it should be global variable. Therefore, rhapsody generates the code by using extern to make it global.

You can check this code generation [reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/customize-code-generation-using-ibm-rational-rhapsody-c#Visibility) and if you search *"public"*, *"namespace"* and *"extern"* you can easily find what is going on background.

If you share your model maybe I can help you in better way.

Comment: It's C actually. Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: Same explanation is valid alao for C

Comment: BTW if this question is about C you should have tagged it on C! So that no one could give you answer about another languages.